# Least Recently Used Cache that runs in constant time

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap, time-complexity

I'm trying to create a cache that operates in constant time and follows a least recently used eviction policy. It uses a hash map to store the data and a linked list to keep track of the order the data has been requested. The head would be the least recently requested and the tail being the most recently requested.

Everything works in O(1) except for when a user requests an item already in the cache and the linked list has to remove the item from the list and add it as the tail. How could I implement a system that could make the most recently requested item that is already in the cache, and therefor the linked list, the tail in O(1)?

Comment: How do you get a hash map to work in constant time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use case for a doubly-linked list. If you thread a doubly-linked rather than singly-linked list through your elements and have a dummy head and tail object, you can splice out an element from the list by writing

```
elem.next.prev = elem.prev;
elem.prev.next = elem.next;
```

You can then put the element at the tail by writing

```
elem.next = tail;
elem.prev = tail.prev;
tail.prev = elem;
elem.prev.next = elem;
```

Since there’s only a constant number of pointer juggles here, this runs in time O(1).

This sort of technique is often used in OS kernels to move objects like threads between different run queues because it’s extremely fast.

Comment: I think your code is going to insert `elem` between the tail node and the node before tail node, instead of making it a tail node

Comment: @mangusta Yes, that's correct. I'm assuming we have a dummy head and tail node, so inserting just before the end of the physical list corresponds to inserting at the end of the logical list.